# Shell command to change macOS Time Machine update rate

Tags: macos, command-line, plist, timemachine

After seeing [mathiasbynens' dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos), I've decided that I want to start building a script to configure all my system preferences to my liking.

As part of this, I need to decrease the Time Machine update rate (in order to reduce wear levels on my NAS' hard disk).

After doing some reading online [1], I have concluded that the file I need to edit is `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-helper.plist`.

I know that this is possible via the `defaults` command. Here is the section of the file I want to change:

```
$ defaults read /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-helper LaunchEvents
{
    "com.apple.xpc.activity" =     {
        "com.apple.backupd-auto" =         {
            AllowBattery = 1;
            Delay = 3600;
            GracePeriod = 1800;
            Interval = 3600;
            PowerNap = 1;
            Priority = Utility;
            Repeating = 1;
        };
    };
}
```

The problem is that, due to the dots (`.`) in the path to the `Delay` property, I cannot figure out how to specify said path directly.

I have tried `LaunchEvents.\"com.apple.xpc.activity\"`, `'LaunchEvents."com.apple.xpc.activity"'`, and many variations thereof.

[1] https://staff.eecis.udel.edu/docs/timemachine/frequency/

Answer (score 0):

I took a copy of `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-helper.plist` and saved it elsewhere as `a.plist`:

```
cp "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-helper.plist" /tmp/a.plist
```

Then I played around with `PlistBuddy` until I got this which seems to work:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :LaunchEvents:com.apple.xpc.activity:com.apple.backupd-auto:Interval 7200" /tmp/a.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

Vaguely related to the original topic, it is way more flexible to disable time machine's auto scheduling and replace it with either TimeMachineEditor or simply create a launchd(8) rule. Eg. via LaunchControl
[image]